# How to I send an external POST request to a Django app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-requests

I need to send a POST request to a Django app to update a dictionary that the app references.
The urls.py file looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [url(r'^post/', views.receive]
```

and the views.py file looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import json

def receive(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contents = json.parse(request.body)
```

When I try to send a POST to the url in urls.py with a simple body, I get a forbidden error. How do I structure my code/app to receive and record data from a POST? Is Django able to do this?

Comment: Is that the whole `receive()` method? Views need to return an `HttpResponse` e.g. `return HttpResponse(contents)`. See the documentation on [writing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/views/)